# Adding Path to terminal OS X

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh

I am having some problem with my Path in the terminal. Basically, each time I open a terminal I have to export PATH="/Users/MyName/anaconda/bin: $PATH" in order to be able to use Conda commands. Normally, if I put this command it should remain forever no? However, I have to do it every time if not I get Conda command not found. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Best,

Etienne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vim.
If you haven't vim installed you can download it on the web (for example [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/macosxvim/))

In a terminal, if you have vim installed do the following :

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Then add your line :

```
export PATH="/Users/MyName/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Then close all your terminals opened and reopen one.
Then it will be loaded for your profile, you needn't to export it manually each time.

You can have a look on google on how to use vim (search for basic commands : input write and escape file edit).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `zsh` edit your `.zshrc` file and modify the line starting with something like `export PATH=` to something like:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

To check your path you can then run:

```
echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}
```

It will print your existing paths and in the order they will be used.